# Search tweets from multiple users with a certain hashtag?

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I'd like to fetch tweets with the Twitter Search API that have a certain hashtag and from a list of Twitter users.

This returns all the tweets from two users, but I only need tweets with a certain hashtag
https://search.twitter.com/search.json?&q=from:stevdobb+OR+from:dummytwitteruser

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis No that's just for a hashtag. I need tweets with a hashtag from a list of users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine users and hashtags in your search query. i.e. you could do something like this:

https://search.twitter.com/search.json?&q=from:stevdobb+OR+from:dummytwitteruser+%23file

This returns tweets from "stevdobb" or "dummytwitteruser" that contain a #file hashtag